# How can I transfer reports from one server to another? SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two servers reports of them will be disabled but the reports that will be disabled needs to be sent to another server, is there any way of doing this? What better way?

I have several files. RDL to transfer

Both servers are 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this in the past using the web GUI on the reports server.  Download the report as a .rdl file from one server, and upload the .rdl file to create the report on the new server.

(then delete the original version from the first server, of course)

MSDN has a nice walkthrough of this :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2012/12/19/moving-rdl-files-from-one-reporting-services-instance-to-another.aspx

Comment: I have several files to be rdl trasfer, this takes a long time, say days

Comment: if you need to do it in bulk, this tool could help : http://sqlserverfinebuild.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Install%20Reporting%20Services%20Scripter
(although I don't have any experience with it myself)

Comment: or if you want to completely move the old database across to the new server you can follow these steps :
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2692/migrating-sql-reporting-services-to-a-new-server-by-moving-the-reporting-services-databases/

Comment: Thanks! I will check the tool, move the database is not interesting because there is already some reports on the target ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can query the SSRS database for the info.

```
 SELECT

     NAME,CAST(CAST(CONTENT AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS ReportXml

    FROM dbo.Catalog

   WHERE TYPE = 2
```

I think that's right.  The Type value (2) may be off, but fish around, you can find it.

At the end of the day........the SSRS is just "info in some tables".........that can be massaged into another SSRS database.

Comment: It's not enough. You have to move, also, the data sources (at least).

Comment: Right.  Change the TYPE where clause.......and you can get the DataSources.

Comment: .............WHERE TYPE = 5

Comment: Except `dbo.Catalog` table there are, also, these tables: `dbo.DataSource` (shared and not shared DS), `dbo.DataSets` (shared data sources). And how can be transferred access rights for every report? The key point is that these tables are not documented. See Graham Griffiths's comment for a possible solution.